# OID 2.25.x in SNMP

Tags: snmp, uuid

Want to write a snmp-module for internal purposes.
As i've read, the OID-tree 2.25 is usable without regristration, but there should be used UUIDs. In a rfc is written, that OID-values can't be bigger than 2^32-1.

How then to use `2.25.<uuid>` via smnp?

EDIT: A registrated enterprise OID is not always useful, as there seems to be a OID-tree existing that could be handled like rfc-ipv4-addresses.

But one central point of the question is also, why there should be used 16 byte long UUIDs if SNMP seems to be able only four bytes as OID? Or did i miss somewhat how to use the 2.25-tree? Or is the whole idea a completly wrong thought?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Why do you (think you) need to use a UUID in your OID? What problem have you encountered while doing so?

Comment: To register an actual enterprise OID for your organization, see 
http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page

Comment: For example: administrating several server's. SNMP is a ideal protocol for monitoring. But for some checks a public oid is not useful (e.g. regular maintenance reminding or other special checks). 2.25 does not need a regristration, because it's nearly impossible colliding two uuid's. So it's perfect for such purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my reading there seems, unfortunately, to be poor tools' support for UUID OIDs.

Quoting [oid-info.com](http://www.oid-info.com/faq.htm#size-limitations) ...

> **Are there size limitations for OID encoding?**
>
> The OID standards have no limit whatsoever about the depth of an OID in the OID tree (i.e., number of arcs) and **the size of the integer associated to each OID arc**. However, some tools may have size limitations (or bugs) ....

Similarily at [viathinksoft.de](http://www.viathinksoft.de/~daniel-marschall/asn.1/oid_facts.html#chap4) it says :

> The OID standards have no limit whatsoever about the depth of an OID in the OID tree (i.e., number of arcs) and the size of the integer associated to each OID arc. However, some tools may have size limitations.
>
> Possible limits could be...
>
> Limitation of an arc size, e.g. 2.999.18446744073709551615
>
> Limitation of the total size of the dot-notation of an OID (string length)
>
> Limitation of the depth of a OID
>
> Limitation of the value of an attribute inside a Rec. ITU-T X.509 certificate
>
> Limitation of the length of the DER encoded data

Comment: After researching a it more, i found the rfc from my question:
The limitations seem not to be created by the tools, but by [rfc2578](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2578#page-15). Refer to section 3.5. But the essence of your answer seems to be "There is no chance to use UUIDs for SNMP". And that is an answer i have to accept. 
I thought that there is maybe a way to transform 2.25.<uuid> to something usable with SNMP (without shortening the UUID, which increases the chance to create collisions).